Why do objects in circular motion move outwards instead of inwards?
I know that whenever an object undergoes circular motion then it has a centripetal acceleration towards the centre and a tangential acceleration. Due to these accelerations I had thought that ab object kept on platform performing circular motion would move inwards. I tried this by keeping a pen cap on a book and spinning it. The cap went outwards. I do not understand why this is happening. If I had seen it from the fram of the book then I could understand that centrifugal force would have caused it but I'm observing it from the ground frame. Even in problems in my physics book where objects are kept in grooves of rotating bodies they move outwards.
Please help me understand why this is so.

"Due to these accelerations I had thought that ab object kept on platform performing circular motion would move inwards". Why would you think that?

This question is similar to: Why horse rides in a merry-go-round swing outward?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

See also https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/337342/

I think the "ultimate" reason for this behavior is Newton's First Law. Any material body will continue in a straight line at constant speed, except as acted upon by a force, which will accelerate it according to Newton's 2nd Law, $F=ma$ in the direction of the force.
If you take this as your starting point, that objects naturally want to travel in straight lines, then ask yourself "How can I make an object travel in a circle?" The only way to do so is to constantly apply a force pulling or pushing towards the center of the circle.

The straightforward answer is that : It happened due to the inertia of the pen cap ( or any object moving in circle ).
Let me explain:
Say , there is body on a horizontal , uniformly rotating , rough platform . Consider an instant in its rotation .
We know that , it's instantaneous velocity is tangential to its circular path i.e. it's inertia of motion wants it to move in that particular direction which is the direction away from the circular path ( not necessarily radially away ).

But what's stopping it ?

As I mentioned we considered the platform to be rough and the body must have some mass , which makes friction act upon it . In this case the friction force is the centripetal force and what is does is not to pull the object in but instead oppose it's inertia to move out of the path.

So , if there is friction, why does the cap gone out ?

It's because the friction is not enough to oppose the inertia there ( either the book surface is somewhat smooth or the pen cap is very light ).
Let me ask you , what is the magnitude of centripetal force ? It's: ( $\omega$ being the angular velocity of the platform ( object ) )
$$F_{centripetal} = m\omega^2r$$
So , if you try to put the cap and move the book with low angular velocity, the friction force required would be less and as it is the centripetal force there and since the book would provide enough friction in this case , the cap would not go anywhere and would revolve along with the book .Here , the friction would be enough to oppose the low inertia.
You might find this one useful for understanding about centripetal and centrifugal forces.

When you swing a ball around in a circle, and suddenly cut the string, which way does it fly?
Away from the circle. At any point during the circular orbit, the object has a tangential direction and due to Newton's 1st law it would keep this direction, which is outwards, if nothing pulled it inwards.
